# How to disable built-in Permanent private browsing Tor?

Tags: configuration, private, settings

Tor 9.0.5 always opens in Permanent Private browsing mode, is there any solution to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

**Not recommended.**

Navigate to `about:preferences#privacy` and uncheck "Always use private browsing mode".